# How can I remove the error bad operand type for unary +: 'str'. in a my looped sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I nearly got this code right, since it's only about dictionaries. The only problem I encountered is the error is bad operand type for unary +: 'str'.

Here's my code:

```
express_file = {'TPLEX':'Pangasinan', 'SLEX':'Subic', 'Cavitex':'Bacoor,Cavite','MCX':'Muntinlupa','Star Tollway':'Laguna'}
for x,y in express_file.items():
    print(x,'runs through',+y+ '.')
print('The following Expressway are included in this data set:')
for x in express_file.keys():
    print(x)
print('\nThe following Provinces are included in this data set:')
for x in express_file.values():
    print(x)
```

### Traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-782fcd7b686e> in <module>
      1 express_file = {'TPLEX':'Pangasinan', 'SLEX':'Subic', 'Cavitex':'Bacoor,Cavite','MCX':'Muntinlupa','Star Tollway':'Laguna'}
      2 for x,y in express_file.items():
----> 3     print(x,'runs through',+y+ '.')
      4 print('The following Expressway are included in this data set:')
      5 for x in express_file.keys():

TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- print with an f-string
- [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```py
# replace print(x,'runs through',+y+ '.')
# with
print(f'{x} runs through {y}.'
# or with
print(x,'runs through ' +y+ '.')  # note the added space after through and the removal of the ,
```

### Updated script

```py
express_file = {'TPLEX':'Pangasinan', 'SLEX':'Subic', 'Cavitex':'Bacoor,Cavite','MCX':'Muntinlupa','Star Tollway':'Laguna'}
for x,y in express_file.items():
    print(f'{x} runs through {y}.')
print('The following Expressway are included in this data set:')
for x in express_file.keys():
    print(x)
print('\nThe following Provinces are included in this data set:')
for x in express_file.values():
    print(x)

[out]:
TPLEX runs through Pangasinan.
SLEX runs through Subic.
Cavitex runs through Bacoor,Cavite.
MCX runs through Muntinlupa.
Star Tollway runs through Laguna.
The following Expressway are included in this data set:
TPLEX
SLEX
Cavitex
MCX
Star Tollway

The following Provinces are included in this data set:
Pangasinan
Subic
Bacoor,Cavite
Muntinlupa
Laguna
```

Answer (score 0):

```
express_file = {'TPLEX':'Pangasinan', 'SLEX':'Subic', 'Cavitex':'Bacoor,Cavite','MCX':'Muntinlupa','Star Tollway':'Laguna'}
for x,y in express_file.items():
    print(x,'runs through'+y+ '.')
print('The following Expressway are included in this data set:')
for x in express_file.keys():
    print(x)
print('\nThe following Provinces are included in this data set:')
for x in express_file.values():
    print(x)
```

You should remove the comma beside +y+.

Comment: oh, my bad, sorry about that. Let me retry it again